# John's ellipsoid of a polytope

Tags: convex-polytopes, convex-geometry, convexity, convex-analysis

Suppose that $X$ is $\mathbb R^n$ with some polyhedral norm, that is, the unit ball of $X$ is an $n$-dimensional polytope. Assume that the John ellipsoid of $X$ is an Euclidean ball that touches every face of the ball of $X$.

Is it true that we can find $n$ orthonormal vectors which make the ball of $X$ invariant under permuting their order and sign changing? (That is, the symmetry group of $[-1,1]^n$ is a subgroup of the symmetry group of the ball of $X$?)

Comment: Either I'm misunderstanding the question, or the norm whose unit ball is a regular hexagon in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is a counterexample.

Comment: Do you really want the symmetry group of $[-1, 1]^n$, or only of $\{-1, 1\}^n$?  Do you really want the full symmetry group of $\{-1, 1\}^n$, or only the signed permutations $\mu_2 \wr \mathfrak S_{\{-1, 1\}}$?

Comment: @LSpice, yes, the signed permutations. Thanks.